# cmd dos check if a remote FTP folder exists

Tags: batch-file, ftp, directory, dos, exists

I want to know how to check if FTP directory exists, using a batch dos or command.

PS:
Obviously I do not need the root of the server, but a subdirectory, otherwise I would have been enough ping it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ftp script that tries to change to the directory and then parse the output looking for the 550 error code that says you cannot. Something like the following works for me...

```
@Echo off

echo open ftp.mysite.com>test.ftp
echo ftpusername>>test.ftp
echo ftppassword>>test.ftp
echo cd %1>>test.ftp
echo quit>>test.ftp

for /f %%i in ('ftp -s:test.ftp') do if {%%i} EQU {550} echo Does not exist
```